# Explode Depth Search in UNIX

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, search

I've a following data in file which has user and supervisor relationship.

```
user |supervisor |id
-----|-----------|----
a    |   b       | 1
b    |   c       | 2
c    |   d       | 3
e    |   b       | 4
```

I want to explode the relationship hierarchy between the user and supervisor as below.

```
user |supervisor |id
-----|-----------|----
a    |   b       | 1
a    |   c       | 1
a    |   d       | 1
b    |   c       | 2
b    |   d       | 2  
c    |   d       | 3
e    |   b       | 4
e    |   c       | 4
e    |   d       | 4
```

As you see, for the user 'a', the immediate supervisor is 'b' but again 'b' has 'c' as its supervisor. So indirectly 'c' is supervisor for 'a' as well and so on. Such as, my aim is to explode the hierarchy at any level for a given user. What is the best way to implement this in Unix ?

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming that each user appears
in the input file (in the “User” column) only once. 
I’m further assuming that the vertical bar (`|`) separators
are actually in the file,
and that they are always separated from the data by whitespace,
and that the header line is *not* actually present.

Here’s a two-pass solution using `awk`. 
The first pass builds an array containing everybody’s supervisor;
the second pass builds the output:

```
awk 'pass==1 { super[$1] = $3; }
     pass==2 {
                print
                user=$3
                while (super[user] != "") {
                        print $1, "|", super[user], "|", $5
                        user=super[user]
                }
             }
    ' pass=1 data pass=2 data
```

This will produce output that’s not properly aligned. 
To fix that, pipe it through `column -t`. 
Or we can format the output from within the `awk` script;
if you want that, specify the formatting rules you want.

By the way, this operation is generally known as [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

Answer (score 0):

Complex ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR<3{ h=(h=="")? $0 : h ORS $0 }NR>2{ uid[$1]=$5; us[$1]=$3 }
     END{ 
         print h; 
         for (u in uid) { 
             id=uid[u]; spvr=us[u]; printf("%-5s|%-11s|%-4s\n",u,spvr,id); 
             while (spvr in uid) { 
                 spvr=us[spvr]; printf("%-5s|%-11s|%-4s\n",u,spvr,id) 
             } 
         }
     }' yourfile
```

The output:

```
user |supervisor |id
-----|-----------|----
a    |b          |1   
a    |c          |1   
a    |d          |1   
b    |c          |2   
b    |d          |2   
c    |d          |3   
e    |b          |4   
e    |c          |4   
e    |d          |4
```

---

Details:

- `NR<3{ h=(h=="")? $0 : h ORS $0 }` - capturing *header* lines
- `uid[$1]=$5` - ***user-id*** relation array
- `us[$1]=$3` - ***user-supervisor*** relation array
- `spvr=us[u]` - the 1st *supervisor* for the current *user*
- `while (spvr in uid) { ... }` - while *supervisor* is in ***user*** list, get parent *supervisor*

Answer (score 0):

My awk solution (using output formats from RomanPerekhrest). Basically, there are two relevant loops. First, if a new supervisor is processed for a user, then all dependencies of that supervisor(i.e. supervisor-chains) must be added to the user. After that, a second loop looks for all other users, which have the currently processed user as a dependency and all dependencies of the current user are added to them.:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
# file process_it.awk
BEGIN {

    FS="|";
}

NR<3 {

    h=(h==""? $0 : h ORS $0)
}

NR>2 {

   gsub(/ /, "", $0)
   curr_user=$1;
   curr_supervisor=$2;
   curr_id=$3;
   print curr_user, curr_supervisor;
   arr[curr_user][curr_supervisor]++;
   id[curr_user]=curr_id;

   if(isarray(arr[curr_supervisor])) {
       for(sub_indx in arr[curr_supervisor])
           arr[curr_user][sub_indx]++;
    }
    else
        delete arr[curr_supervisor];

    for(indx in arr) {

        if(isarray(arr[indx])) {

            for(sub_indx in arr[indx]) {

                if(sub_indx==curr_user) {

                    for(sub_indx2 in arr[curr_user])
                    arr[indx][sub_indx2]++;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}

END {
    print h;

    for(i in arr) {

        if(isarray(arr[i])) {

            for(j in arr[i])
                printf "%-5s|%-11s|%-3s\n", i, j, id[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
awk -f process_it.awk your_file.txt
```